# Storage of c variables in memory

Tags: c++, c, variables, memory

I want to know which variables are stored in stack, heap, etc. 
Suppose i have a variable, an array , a pointer , etc. Where will these be stored(stack,heap,unknown)? And where are static variables stored. Where will a variable, an array, a pointer be stored when they are declared as static? And where are global variables and variables declared as extern stored.

Comment: with something general like this, a little googling goes a long way buddy

Comment: Might as well read the standard yourself with a broad question like this.

Comment: @Steve: Do you have some examples?  My Google search came up a bit weak.

Comment: Ah, here we go: http://bharat226.blogspot.com/2012/07/where-are-various-variables-stored-in-c.html

Comment: You might want to read this [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the latest language standard, particularly section 6.2.4.  It won't tell you whether something it stored on the *stack* or the *heap* (that's up to the implementation), but it will give you the rules for a variable's lifetime.  Couple that with the spec for your system and the object file format being used, and you can probably guess where things go.

Answer (score 0):

Statics and globals are stored in global data memory (not stack or heap).  extern has effect on storage.